# How can I buy Yosemite apps from a Mavericks installation?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I am trying to buy an app which runs on 10.10 only, from a computer that has 10.9 installed. The App Store does not like it:

[image: mac app store screenshot]

*Translation: Your purchase could not be completed. OmniOutliner could not be installed […], as it requires […] 10.10 or newer*

In other words: I would like to just **perform the buying process**, **not install** the application on my computer (Which is not compatible – yet. Long story). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Nota bene: I can not buy from Omnigroup directly, or use a gift card. Another long story.

Comment: If you are trying to purchase this for another person's Yosemite Mac, how about purchasing an Apple Store gift card?

Comment: Did you consider buying it from their site (https://store.omnigroup.com), instead of the App Store?

Comment: This *may* be one of those situations where "momma knows best." Where momma is Apple and won't let you do such a thing because it's not compatible. And I am unsure that you can then copy the app to another Mac, there may be some sort of copy protection/DRM to prevent copying to another Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a fringe case. I can report that as of Summer of 2015, buying an app for a newer OS version from an older version is not possible. **I solved the issue** by installing 10.10 on a different partition, and bought the app from there.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to Yosemite on your main partition? Maverick is becoming out of date and soon El Captain will be out soon. This will make Mavericks 2 years old! When El Captain comes out new apps may not be supported on OS X 10.9 (or even 10.10!) due to swift 2 released with El Captain. This will make apps more efficient and more powerful (with metal)